# How can I add Custom Fields that I need to be included in Opportunity Field History when they are changed/updated?

Tags: opportunity, custom-field, opportunity-lineitem, field-history

Right now I have Budget fields, say Budget Field 1, 2, and 3. When I update these budget fields, **Opportunity Field History** does not capture the updated information that was input into these fields. When I update those fields again, the Opportunity Field History once again does not include the updated amounts. I have tried going into these budget fields, which are simple **Currency Fields**, and enable them to be used by Field History, but there is no checkbox to enable.

Comment: I suspect things are not as simple as you say. Are they Formula Currency fields? Do you have Multi-Currency enabled? Are you using Dated Currency Conversion? There's no ordinary reason I can think of why you wouldn't be able to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Setup -> Build -> Customize -> Opportunity -> Fields. At the top is a button called "Set History Tracking" click that and then check the fields you want to track then click save.

Comment: I knew it had to be something this simple. I can't believe I overlooked that button.